# What's the easiest way to back up EC2 instances automatically?

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, amazon-s3

I'm worried I might log in one day and my fully configured instance has been removed. I would like to be able to back it up daily to S3 but frustratingly this is not a simple setting in the console.

Is there a simple managed solution that can take care of backups, and should the unthinkable happen, allow me to simple restore it straight away?

Comment: See also some answers in here: http://serverfault.com/questions/238083/whats-the-easiest-way-to-auto-backup-an-ec2-instance/447679#447679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use an EBS backed instance - you'll pay a little extra for the EBS storage, but it's worth it for the peace of mind.  Use one of the available EBS backed AMIs, or follow [this Server Fault answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082724/amazon-ec2-swap-root-instance-store-device-with-ebs-device) to roll your own from a running instance.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to recommend my open source tool "ec2-automate-backup" in combination - the tool will snapshot one or more than one EBS volumes - your server (or servers) can then be restored from these snapshots - the tool is available at http://awsmissingtools.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use EBS volumes for your data and keep it snapshot daily/hourly using cron job.

Once you created a snapshot, you can create a new volume from that and attached to your new instance(create with same AMI you have). You can also automate your AMI, where you can pass a user-data(ex. volume-id) upon startup for example, which will auto attached the volume and snapshot it.